# Is the future continuous correct here? 'I'll be waiting for her response.'

Tags: sentence-structure, politeness

Here is a context : I wrote an email with request to person A, but she hasn't replied. So, I decided to ask the same person B. Person B replied that she can't help and I should ask person A.

Now I want to reply to person B. Is it ok ( both polite and formal ) ?

> I wrote to A few days ago, but she hasn't replied. I'll be waiting for her response. Thank you anyway.

Especially, I am not sure whether use of future continuous is correct and if it is polite enough.

Comment: You can add *yet* to your perfect tense. As for the future continuous, it's politer and less direct than just saying *I'll wait for her response*, so the continuous form works too.

Answer (score 1):

"I am waiting for her response" or "I am waiting on her response" or "I await her response" could all be used. The best option is probably the middle one.

You also dont need to mention that she has not replied AND that you are waiting on her response as either sentence implies the other. This is grammatically acceptable but it is called tautology or redundancy. Essentially you are saying the same information twice needlessly.

Comment: I think the A and B were a bit confused in the question, so I edited to make the situation clearer. My edit may have affected your answer.

Comment: "But she hasn't replied" doesn't necessarily imply that you are waiting on her response. In fact the OP has not sat back to wait, they've emailed person B in the meantime. Or now that they know person A is the right person to ask, they might email them again, or phone them, rather than waiting.

Comment: If you note that something that you expect to happen eventually has not happened, it does imply that you are waiting for it to happen. This does not mean you are idle in the matter but simply that the situation is out of your hands. The "waiting" is not "sitting back" or "being idle". It just refers to anticipation of the upcoming event. In this context it means that your progress is dependent on something you have no power to advance the progress of.